# Merge queries with Union Select

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to merge two queries with Union Select, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong... I have used this method before with no problem, but there must be something that I don't realize about that is giving me problems.

The two queries I'm trying to merge are as follows:

```
SELECT Parejas.[ID Pareja], Parejas.NombrePareja AS [Nombre Pareja / Paciente], Parejas.FechaAlta AS [Fecha de alta], Count(Sesiones.[ID sesión]) AS [CuentaDeID sesión], Profesional.Nombre
FROM Paciente INNER JOIN (Profesional INNER JOIN (Parejas INNER JOIN Sesiones ON Parejas.[ID Pareja] = Sesiones.[ID Pareja]) ON Profesional.[ID Profesional] = Sesiones.[ID Profesional]) ON Paciente.[ID Paciente] = Parejas.Pacientes.Value
WHERE (((Parejas.FechaAlta)>[Formularios]![Consulta_duracion]![Texto15]))
GROUP BY Parejas.[ID Pareja], Parejas.NombrePareja, Parejas.FechaAlta, Profesional.Nombre;
```

And the second one is this one:

```
SELECT Parejas.[ID Pareja], Paciente.Nombre AS [Nombre Pareja / Paciente], Paciente.FechaAlta AS [Fecha de alta], Count(Sesiones.[ID sesión]) AS [CuentaDeID sesión], Profesional.Nombre
FROM (Profesional INNER JOIN (Paciente INNER JOIN Sesiones ON Paciente.[ID Paciente] = Sesiones.[ID Paciente]) ON Profesional.[ID Profesional] = Sesiones.[ID Profesional]) INNER JOIN Parejas ON Paciente.[ID Paciente] = Parejas.Pacientes.Value
WHERE (((Paciente.FechaAlta)>[Formularios]![Consulta_duracion]![Texto15]))
GROUP BY Parejas.[ID Pareja], Paciente.Nombre, Paciente.FechaAlta, Profesional.Nombre;
```

I use the Union clause to merge both queries, but I always get the following error message:

"your query does not include the specified expression 'ID Pareja" as part of an aggregate function"

May be any of you do have any clue about what the problem is?

Thank you so much!

edit: I attach a image with all the tables and relations. As you can see, "Paciente" and "Sesiones" are the main tables, over which all others are designed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyFJ4.png)

Comment: Its problem with uneven id aggregation on unioning both selects try union first then apply group by it should work

Comment: Save each query as a query. Then union the two saved queries using a straight union query.

Comment: I have saved each one as independent queries, and it doesn't work. They do work separately, but not when I make a union query.

Comment: Hi Himanshu, thanks a lot for your comment. How is that? I don't understand what you mean by "union first then apply group by"...

Comment: Build a UNION of two simple SELECT statements, no grouping. Then use that query in another to do the aggregation.

Comment: Have you tried `UNION ALL` instead?

Comment: With such similar queries, this might be a database design question. You might need normalization to avoid redundancy of records. Can you provide the background "story" of your relational model? What are you capturing between *Professional*, *Patient*, *Couples*, and *Session* tables? Any 1-to-1, 1-to-many, many-to-many relationships? Please edit post and not answer as a long comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should yield a valid `UNION` query -

```
SELECT u.*
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        Parejas.[ID Pareja], 
        Parejas.NombrePareja AS [Nombre Pareja / Paciente], 
        Parejas.FechaAlta AS [Fecha de alta], 
        Count(Sesiones.[ID sesión]) AS [CuentaDeID sesión], 
        Profesional.Nombre
    FROM 
        Paciente INNER JOIN 
        (
            Profesional INNER JOIN 
            (
                Parejas INNER JOIN Sesiones ON 
                Parejas.[ID Pareja] = Sesiones.[ID Pareja]
            ) 
            ON Profesional.[ID Profesional] = Sesiones.[ID Profesional]
        ) 
        ON Paciente.[ID Paciente] = Parejas.Pacientes.Value
    WHERE 
        Parejas.FechaAlta > [Formularios]![Consulta_duracion]![Texto15]
    GROUP BY 
        Parejas.[ID Pareja], 
        Parejas.NombrePareja, 
        Parejas.FechaAlta, 
        Profesional.Nombre
) u
UNION ALL
SELECT v.*
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        Parejas.[ID Pareja], 
        Paciente.Nombre AS [Nombre Pareja / Paciente], 
        Paciente.FechaAlta AS [Fecha de alta], 
        Count(Sesiones.[ID sesión]) AS [CuentaDeID sesión], 
        Profesional.Nombre
    FROM 
        (
            Profesional INNER JOIN 
            (
                Paciente INNER JOIN Sesiones ON 
                Paciente.[ID Paciente] = Sesiones.[ID Paciente]
            )
            ON Profesional.[ID Profesional] = Sesiones.[ID Profesional]
        )
        INNER JOIN Parejas ON 
        Paciente.[ID Paciente] = Parejas.Pacientes.Value
    WHERE 
        Paciente.FechaAlta > [Formularios]![Consulta_duracion]![Texto15]
    GROUP BY 
        Parejas.[ID Pareja], 
        Paciente.Nombre, 
        Paciente.FechaAlta, 
        Profesional.Nombre
) v
```

(Untested of course)

Comment: I think this proposal is near to getting it. When I try it, it doesn't work, saying "access syntax error missing operator in query expression "CuentaDeID sesión" ". I have tryied to do it without the Count(Sesiones.[ID sesión]) and then it works (at least it shows all the registers with the selected filters), but without counting the total number of registers, whis is precisely the most important part. May be there is some problem with an operator or something?

Comment: @juanjoalv205 I can't see any syntax errors in the SQL I have posted, and so do you receive that error when running the query in my post in isolation, or are you running another query which references the above query?

Comment: No, I'm running it in isolation and it returns "syntax error"... I'm really clueless

Comment: @juanjoalv205 Try changing `Count(Sesiones.[ID sesión])` to `Count(*)` in both queries; though, this could yield different results if `Sesiones.[ID sesión]` can be null.

Comment: No, it still doesnt work. Besides, if in Count(Sesiones.[ID sesión]) y change it to Count(*), I can also delete the statement AS [CuentaDeID sesión], then the error mesage changes to "Your query does not include the specified expresion 'ID Pareja' as part of an aggregated function"

Comment: @juanjoalv205 It's difficult to advise without seeing some sample data for the tables/queries referenced...